# arrays of integers

Tags: php, arrays, integer

I have an array:

```
$age = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31");
```

and in my html I'm getting the values in the array to be a in dropdown list:

```
   foreach($age as $val)
    {echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$val.'</option>'; }?>
```

was wondering how can I generate an array of range of numbers so I can easily change it in the future instead of manual keying all the numbers?
can I do something like this?

```
    $minNum = 18;
    $maxNum = 80;
    $age = [];
    while($minNum <= $maxNum){
    $age.push($minNum++);
    }
```

when I do the above I got undefined push function error

Comment: `age.push("" + ($minNum++))` should work. You can leave out the braces around the increment. It's merely for better view.

Comment: That isn't JavaScript. That's PHP. Care to edit the tags?

Comment: @4castle, the middle is php, the last snippet is js

Comment: @PatrickEvans I'm not convinced. OP says `push` is undefined.

Comment: I'm getting error:  Call to undefined function push()

Comment: @rory-h javascript variables don't need to start with `$`. If you use it, it should probably be because you want to make clear that it's holding a jQuery object, for example.

Comment: I meant to tag PHP. my mind was all over the place. Sorry

Comment: PHP doesn't use dot operator's (`.`) to access methods, its a concatenation operator. Also you push elements onto an array in PHP with [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) or short syntax `$age[] = "someval";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, arrays don't have any functions. You would use [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

However, PHP has a built-in for this: [`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

```
$age = range(18, 80);
```